# Sonar - When instantiating a SimpleDateFormat object, specify a Locale

Tags: java, sonarqube

Below is my method to set the date in yyyy-MM-dd format code is working as expected but I am getting sonar error - When instantiating a SimpleDateFormat object, specify a Locale. Any Suggestion experts how to resolve this issue ?

```
    public String getEndDate() throws ParseException {
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.setTime(new Date());
        Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
        return f.format(date.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you read the javadoc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify locale as in the following example.

```
public static String getEndDate() {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(new Date());
    Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH); // Locale
    date.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
    return f.format(date.getTime());
}
```

It is noteworthy that if you omit the locale, it will use `Locale.getDefault()` which is based on the host  JVM. It could be a desirable feature.